# Python (NumPy, SciPy), finding the null space of a matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, svd

I'm trying to find the null space (solution space of Ax=0) of a given matrix. I've found two examples, but I can't seem to get either to work. Moreover, I can't understand what they're doing to get there, so I can't debug. I'm hoping someone might be able to walk me through this.

The documentation pages ([`numpy.linalg.svd`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.3.x/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html), and [`numpy.compress`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html)) are opaque to me. I learned to do this by creating the matrix `C = [A|0]`, finding the reduced row echelon form and solving for variables by row. I can't seem to follow how it's being done in these examples.

Thanks for any and all help!

Here is my sample matrix, which is the same as the [wikipedia example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29):

```
A = matrix([
    [2,3,5],
    [-4,2,3]
    ])
```

Method ([found here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2005-June/004650.html), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992947/calculating-the-null-space-of-a-matrix)):

```
import scipy
from scipy import linalg, matrix
def null(A, eps=1e-15):
    u, s, vh = scipy.linalg.svd(A)
    null_mask = (s <= eps)
    null_space = scipy.compress(null_mask, vh, axis=0)
    return scipy.transpose(null_space)
```

When I try it, I get back an empty matrix:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Sep 15 2010, 16:22:56) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
>>> from scipy import linalg, matrix
>>> def null(A, eps=1e-15):
...    u, s, vh = scipy.linalg.svd(A)
...    null_mask = (s <= eps)
...    null_space = scipy.compress(null_mask, vh, axis=0)
...    return scipy.transpose(null_space)
... 
>>> A = matrix([
...     [2,3,5],
...     [-4,2,3]
...     ])  
>>> 
>>> null(A)
array([], shape=(3, 0), dtype=float64)
>>>
```

Comment: The wikipedia page you linked to actually gives a very nice explanation of why you should use an SVD to calculate the null space (or solve) of a matrix when you're dealing with floating point values. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29#Numerical_computation_of_null_space The approach you describe (solving for variables row-by-row) will amplify any rounding errors, etc. (This is the same reason you should almost never explicitly calculate the inverse of a matrix...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears to be working okay for me:

```
A = matrix([[2,3,5],[-4,2,3],[0,0,0]])
A * null(A)
>>> [[  4.02455846e-16]
>>>  [  1.94289029e-16]
>>>  [  0.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, but Wikipedia suggests that the values should be `[ [-.0625], [-1.625], [1] ]`?

Comment: Moreover, it's returning an empty matrix for me `[]`. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Nona Urbiz - It's returning an empty matrix because you're not putting in a row of zeros, as Bashwork (and wikipedia) does above. Also, the null space values returned (`[-0.33, -0.85, 0.52]`) are normalized so that the magnitude of the vector is 1.  The wikipedia example is not normalized.  If you just take `n = null(A)` and have a look at `n / n.max()`, you'll get `[-.0625, -1.625, 1]`.

Comment: @Bashwork - How would I know to programmatically add a row of zeroes? Does the matrix have to be square?

Answer (score 26):

Sympy makes this straightforward.

```
>>> from sympy import Matrix
>>> A = [[2, 3, 5], [-4, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0]]
>>> A = Matrix(A)
>>> A * A.nullspace()[0]
Matrix([
[0],
[0],
[0]])
>>> A.nullspace()
[Matrix([
[-1/16],
[-13/8],
[    1]])]
```

Comment: Exactly the solution I was looking for!

Comment: I believe this approach only works for integers but not for floats :(.

Comment: @Adriaan I just tested with floats and it worked for me.

Answer (score 14):

As of last year (2017), scipy now has a built-in `null_space` method in the `scipy.linalg` module ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.null_space.html)).

The [implementation](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f97ce31736bb3c4a0a0c7db8fde2ee4ebc69e39d/scipy/linalg/decomp_svd.py#L331-L391) follows the canonical SVD decomposition and is pretty small if you have an older version of scipy and need to implement it yourself (see below). However, if you're up-to-date, it's there for you.

```
def null_space(A, rcond=None):
    u, s, vh = svd(A, full_matrices=True)
    M, N = u.shape[0], vh.shape[1]
    if rcond is None:
        rcond = numpy.finfo(s.dtype).eps * max(M, N)
    tol = numpy.amax(s) * rcond
    num = numpy.sum(s > tol, dtype=int)
    Q = vh[num:,:].T.conj()
    return Q
```

Answer (score 13):

You get the SVD decomposition of the matrix `A`. `s` is a vector of eigenvalues. You are interested in almost zero eigenvalues (see $A*x=\lambda*x$ where $\abs(\lambda)<\epsilon$), which is given by the vector of logical values `null_mask`.

Then, you extract from the list `vh` the eigenvectors corresponding to the almost zero eigenvalues, which is exactly what you are looking for: a way to span the null space. Basically, you extract the rows and then transpose the results so that you get a matrix with eigenvectors as columns.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply and help me. Your answer was very helpful to me, but I accepted Bashworks answer as ultimately, it brought me to the solution. The only reason I am able to understand the solution though, is your response.

Comment: No worry, I thought your problem was something else.

Answer (score 4):

A faster but less numerically stable method is to use [a rank-revealing QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRQR_factorization), such as [`scipy.linalg.qr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qr.html) with `pivoting=True`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import qr

def qr_null(A, tol=None):
    Q, R, P = qr(A.T, mode='full', pivoting=True)
    tol = np.finfo(R.dtype).eps if tol is None else tol
    rnk = min(A.shape) - np.abs(np.diag(R))[::-1].searchsorted(tol)
    return Q[:, rnk:].conj()
```

For example:

```
A = np.array([[ 2, 3, 5],
              [-4, 2, 3],
              [ 0, 0, 0]])
Z = qr_null(A)

print(A.dot(Z))
#[[  4.44089210e-16]
# [  6.66133815e-16]
# [  0.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: I tried this out and got different answers on `Matrix([[2, 2, 1, 0], [2, -2, -1, 1]])`.  Using sympy I correctly got:

```
[Matrix([
[   0],
[-1/2],
[   1],
[   0]]),
 Matrix([
[-1/4],
[ 1/4],
[   0],
[   1]])]
```

But with the above method I got:

```
array([[0.00000000e+00, 4.16333634e-17],
       [1.73472348e-16, 0.00000000e+00]])
```

Am I missing something? (I'm decent at linear algebra but I have no idea what this method is - I'm just trying it)

Answer (score 3):

Your method is almost correct.  The issue is that the shape of s returned by the function scipy.linalg.svd is (K,) where K=min(M,N).  Thus, in your example, s only has two entries (the singular values of the first two singular vectors).  The following correction to your null function should allow it to work for any sized matrix.

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg, matrix
def null(A, eps=1e-12):
...    u, s, vh = scipy.linalg.svd(A)
...    padding = max(0,np.shape(A)[1]-np.shape(s)[0])
...    null_mask = np.concatenate(((s <= eps), np.ones((padding,),dtype=bool)),axis=0)
...    null_space = scipy.compress(null_mask, vh, axis=0)
...    return scipy.transpose(null_space)
A = matrix([[2,3,5],[-4,2,3]])
print A*null(A)
>>>[[  4.44089210e-16]
>>> [  6.66133815e-16]]
A = matrix([[1,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])
print null(A)
>>>[[ 0.         -0.70710678]
>>> [ 0.          0.        ]
>>> [ 0.          0.70710678]
>>> [ 1.          0.        ]]
print A*null(A)
>>>[[ 0.  0.]
>>> [ 0.  0.]
>>> [ 0.  0.]
>>> [ 0.  0.]]
```

Comment: I have been using this code in my work and I noticed a problem. An eps value of 1e-15 seems to be too small.  Notably, consider the matrix A = np.ones(13,2).  This code will report that this matrix has a rank 0 null space.  This is due to the scipy.linalg.svd function reporting that the second singular value is above 1e-15.  I don't know much about the algorithms behind this function, however I suggest using eps=1e-12 (and perhaps lower for very large matrices) unless someone with more knowledge can chime in. (In infinite precision the second singular value should be 0).