# A fast way to find an all zero answer

Tags: python, algorithm, math, numpy, optimization

For every array of length n+h-1 with values from 0 and 1, I would like to check if there exists another non-zero array of length n with values from -1,0,1 so that all the h inner products are zero.  My naive way to do this is

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
(n,h)= 4,3
for longtuple in itertools.product([0,1], repeat = n+h-1):
    bad = 0
    for v in itertools.product([-1,0,1], repeat = n):
        if not any(v):
            continue
        if (not np.correlate(v, longtuple, 'valid').any()):
            bad = 1
            break
    if (bad == 0):
        print "Good"
        print longtuple
```

This is very slow if we set `n = 19` and `h = 10` which is what I would like to test.

> My goal is to find a single "Good" array of length `n+h-1`. Is there a
>   way to speed this up so that `n = 19` and `h = 10` is feasible?

The current naive approach takes 2^(n+h-1)3^(n) iterations, each one of which takes roughly n time. That is 311,992,186,885,373,952 iterations for `n = 19` and `h = 10` which is impossible.

**Note 1** Changed `convolve` to `correlate` so that the code considers `v` the right way round.

---

**July 10 2015**

The problem is still open with no solution fast enough for `n=19` and `h=10` given yet.

Comment: Isn't array of only zeros good by this definition?

Comment: "another non-zero array of length n" according to the OP

Comment: "For every array of length n+h-1 with values from 0 and 1, I would like to check if there exists another non-zero array of length n with values from -1,0,1 so that all the h inner products are zero"  What is exactly the relation between the two arrays ?

Comment: and what are "the h inner products" ? -- I think I get what you meant but you should clarify it. You want to consider all shifts of the second array by 0, .., h indices to the right and take the inner products with the first array

Comment: Can you explain it with words ? I can't understand your code if I don't understand your need

Comment: @vib Yes that is right, except it is shifts of the second array by 0, .., h-1 indices so that there are h shifts in total.

Comment: But Dorothy, correct me if I'm wrong, but your code at the moment declares "bad" if ANY of the combinations of the vector v is wrong. I thought you wanted to declare it good if there is ONE that does do the "all zero" trick.

Comment: @Jblasco I want to find a long array so that NO non-zero short array gives all zeros.  So it declares bad if a single non-zero short array gives all zero inner products. `not np.convolve(v, longtuple, 'valid').any()` returns True if all h inner products are zero.

Comment: For your case of interest, isn't the array with a 1 in the middle and all others 0 trivially "good"?

Comment: @btilly I believe not. Take n = 4 and h = 3. Let the long array be [0,0,0,1,0,0] and the short one be [-1, 0, 0, 0] for example. All three inner products are zero.

Comment: Very interesting problem. I can only claim that as n -> inf, you will almost surely get every single vector orthogonal to each other. So you'll get a lot of these sets :)

Comment: You should fix the description of your problem because it's not consistent with the code. You say "I would like to check if there exists another non-zero array of length n..." but in fact the code checks if ALL such vectors have a non-zero dot product.

Comment: @cfh You are right. I just quit as soon as I see a Good one but it isn't very elegant as written.

Comment: @Flying_Banana how are you claiming that? Vectors, on average, are not orthogonal to each other, no matter the dimension.

Comment: Would you accept a proof rather than an algorithm?

Comment: I don't have one yet, but there are a lot of ideas here. First, as has been pointed out, you are looking for vectors in the null space of an hxn Hankel-type matrix with 0,1 entries. There is a fair amount that is known about 0,1 matrices and Hankel matrices. Additionally, you really want to know whether this space intersects the nonzero vertices of the {-1,0,1} hypercube. An algorithmic approach is likely to be computationally intensive unless you use some mathematical machinery to reduce the number of candidates. But there may be a direct proof anyway.

Comment: @JeremyWest if the dimensions are large, any two randomly generated vectors are nearly almost diagonal to each other. You can try this yourself in a python script with say dimension 1000. You will find 99% of the vector pairs you generate are within 5 degrees of being diagonal of each other, or something similar. Its a property of the large dimensions. The math is pretty simple, too.

Comment: @JeremyWest there is a nice proof here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/995623/why-are-randomly-drawn-vectors-nearly-perpendicular-in-high-dimensions

Comment: Sorry, i was on the phone and didn't check. I mean perpendicular.

Comment: @Flying_Banana Yes, but nearly orthogonal is not orthogonal. The probability of being exactly orthogonal is zero (the orthogonal complement of any nontrivial vector space is a set of measure zero). This problem needs the vectors to be exactly orthogonal.

Comment: @JeremyWest if you did not realise the proof I linked worked with generating each coordinate with a floating range. With the given constraint of exactly -1, 0, and 1, there *will* be a lot of exactly orthogonal pairs, and that's what I'm trying to say.

Comment: @Flying_Banana The proof doesn't show what you are claiming. The fact that two vectors are nearly orthogonal in high dimensions is due to the fact that the magnitude of any (unit) vector in one randomly chosen direction is on average 1/n. As n grows large, this goes to zero (but is not zero). Nearly orthogonal is not orthogonal. Again, a hyperplane is a set of measure zero; it is not at all likely that two random vectors are perfectly orthogonal unless they were constructed that way intentionally. Just as random matrices are generally not singular.

Comment: @Flying_Banana It is possible that by looking at the restricted points and subspaces we are considering (due to the -1,0,1 and 0,1 constraints) that we may be more likely to get orthogonal pairs, but that isn't obvious. Furthermore, it is irrelevant. The question isn't whether they are likely, it is whether they happen at all. I just don't think the kind of probabilistic approach you are pursuing is likely to yield useful results for this problem.

Comment: @JeremyWest ahh, but sometimes when a problem doesn't have a straight solution, or if the solution takes too long or too much space, it is helpful to deal with probabilities. Especially when we are in higher dimensions. I am merely trying to let people take the problem on a different perspective, which may or may not help to find a probabilistic answer. And there is nothing wrong with probabilistic answer. A lot of algorithms dealing with large data are probabilistic.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following "meet in the middle" approach.

First, recast the situation in the matrix formulation provided by leekaiinthesky.

Next, note that we only have to consider "short" vectors `s` of the form `{0,1}^n` (i.e., short vectors containing only 0's and 1's) if we change the problem to finding an `h x n` [Hankel matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix) `H` of 0's and 1's such that `Hs1` is never equal to `Hs2` for two different short vectors of 0's and 1's. That is because `Hs1 = Hs2` implies `H(s1-s2)=0` which implies there is a vector `v` of 1's, 0's and -1's, namely `s1-s2`, such that `Hv = 0`; conversely, if `Hv = 0` for `v` in `{-1,0,1}^n`, then we can find `s1` and `s2` in `{0,1}^n` such that `v = s1 - s2` so `Hs1 = Hs2`.

When `n=19` there are only 524,288 vectors `s` in `{0,1}^n` to try; hash the results `Hs` and if the same result occurs twice then `H` is no good and try another `H`. In terms of memory this approach is quite feasible. There are `2^(n+h-1)` Hankel matrices `H` to try; when `n=19` and `h=10` that's 268,435,456 matrices. That's `2^38` tests, or 274,877,906,944, each with about `nh` operations to multiply the matrix `H` and the vector `s`, about 52 trillion ops. That seems feasible, no?

Since you're now only dealing with 0's and 1's, not -1's, you might also be able to speed up the process by using bit operations (shift, and, and count 1's).

**Update**

I implemented my idea in C++. I'm using bit operations to calculate dot products, encoding the resulting vector as a long integer, and using unordered_set to detect duplicates, taking an early exit from a given long vector when a duplicate vector of dot products is found.

I obtained 00000000010010111000100100 for n=17 and h=10 after a few minutes, and 000000111011110001001101011 for n=18 and h=10 in a little while longer. I'm just about to run it for n=19 and h=10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <unordered_set>

/* Count the number of 1 bits in 32 bit int x in 21 instructions.
 * From /Hackers Delight/ by Henry S. Warren, Jr., 5-2
 */
int count1Bits(int x) {
  x = x - ((x >> 1) & 0x55555555);
  x = (x & 0x33333333) + ((x >> 2) & 0x33333333);
  x = (x + (x >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F;
  x = x + (x >> 8);
  x = x + (x >> 16);
  return x & 0x0000003F;
}

int main () {
  const int n = 19;
  const int h = 10;
  std::unordered_set<long> dotProductSet;

  // look at all 2^(n+h-1) possibilities for longVec
  // upper n bits cannot be all 0 so we can start with 1 in pos h
  for (int longVec = (1 << (h-1)); longVec < (1 << (n+h-1)); ++longVec) {

    dotProductSet.clear();
    bool good = true;

    // now look at all n digit non-zero shortVecs
    for (int shortVec = 1; shortVec < (1 << n); ++shortVec) {

      // longVec dot products with shifted shortVecs generates h results
      // each between 0 and n inclusive, can encode as h digit number in
      // base n+1, up to (n+1)^h = 20^10 approx 13 digits, need long
      long dotProduct = 0;

      // encode h dot products of shifted shortVec with longVec
      // as base n+1 integer
      for(int startShort = 0; startShort < h; ++startShort) {
        int shortVecShifted = shortVec << startShort;
        dotProduct *= n+1;
        dotProduct += count1Bits(longVec & shortVecShifted);
      }

      auto ret = dotProductSet.insert(dotProduct);
      if (!ret.second) {
        good = false;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (good) {
      std::cout << std::bitset<(n+h-1)>(longVec) << std::endl;
      break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Second Update**

The program for n=19 and h=10 ran for two weeks in the background on my laptop. At the end, it just exited without printing any results. Barring some kind of error in the program, it looks like there are no long vectors with the property you want. I suggest looking for theoretical reasons why there are no such long vectors. Perhaps some kind of counting argument will work.

Comment: Thank you. I look forward to your results!

Comment: Any luck with the n=19 run?

Comment: Still running .. so no result negative or positive. I had to pause it for 12 hours. I hope it will finish within the next 24.

Comment: From your link: "In linear algebra, a Hankel matrix (or catalecticant matrix), named after Hermann Hankel, is a square matrix". How can you have a 10 x 19 square matrix?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't even catch that. The generalization to rectangular matrices is obvious, and the literature has many references to rectangular Hankel matrices, but both Wikipedia and Mathworld only refer to square matrices. Here's an interesting Beamer presentation on rectangular Hankel matrices: http://www.sam.math.ethz.ch/~mhg/talks/kernelHT-HK-HOcor.pdf

Answer (score 3):

**There may be a faster way***

What you're looking for is related to the concept of the [***kernel*** or ***null space*** of a matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28linear_algebra%29).

In particular, for each n+h-1 "longtuple" and given n, construct an h by n matrix whose rows are the n-subtuples of the longtuple. In other words, if your longtuple is `[0,0,0,1,0,0]` and n = 3, then your matrix is:

```
[[0 0 0]
 [0 0 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 0 0]]
```

Call this matrix **A**. You're looking for a vector **x** such that **Ax** = **0**, where **0** is a vector of all 0s. If such an **x** exists (that is not *itself* all 0s) and can be scaled to contain only {-1, 0, 1}, then you want to throw out **A** and move on to the next longtuple.

I'm not quite sure what the (theoretically most efficient) computational complexity of computing the kernel is, but it seems to be on the order of O(h+n)^3 or so, which is in any case a lot better than O(3^n). See the Wikipedia link above or [Python (NumPy, SciPy), finding the null space of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889142/python-numpy-scipy-finding-the-null-space-of-a-matrix) for some examples on how to compute the kernel.

Anyway, once you identify the kernel, you'll have to do some additional work to figure out if any vectors of the form {-1, 0, 1}^n reside in there, but I don't think that's as big of a computational burden.

***NB**: In the comments, @vib points out that this could in fact be a big computational burden. I am not sure what the best algorithm is for figuring out whether these vectors intersect the kernel. Perhaps it cannot be solved in polynomial time, in which case this answer doesn't provide a speedup to the original problem!

**Example code**

Adapting code from the other Stack Overflow question linked to above for the example you gave in the comments:

```
import scipy
from scipy import linalg, matrix
def null(A, eps=1e-15):
    u, s, vh = scipy.linalg.svd(A)
    null_mask = (s <= eps)
    null_space = scipy.compress(null_mask, vh, axis=0)
    return scipy.transpose(null_space)

A = matrix([[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0]])
print null(A)

#> [[-1.]
#>  [ 0.]
#>  [ 0.]
#>  [ 0.]]
```

The code gives an example (in fact, the same example you gave) of an n-tuple that invalidates `[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]` as a "good" longtuple. If the code returned `[]`, then presumably there's no such n-tuple, and the longtuple is "good". (If the code does return something though, you still have to check the {-1, 0, 1} part.)

**Further thoughts**

Whether such an **x** exists, disregarding the {-1, 0, 1} constraint for now, is equivalent to the question of whether the ***nullity*** (dimension of the kernel) of **A** is greater than 0. This would be equivalent to asking whether the ***rank*** of **A** is equal to n. So if you found some way to be clever about the {-1, 0, 1} constraint and broke it down just to needing to calculate the rank of **A**, I am sure this could be done even faster.

By the way, it seems highly likely that you (or whoever gave you this problem) may know all this already... Otherwise why would you have called the length of the longtuple "n+h-1", if you hadn't already started with the matrix of height h...!

Comment: Your answer is actually very close to mine except that you look at the kernel in R^n and I look at the kernel in (Z/3Z)^n (which lead to the gain 3^n -> 3^(n-h)). In any case, the critical point is this : do you have an efficient way to check whether {-1,0,1}^n intersects the kernel ?

Comment: I do not! That is indeed a critical point. I guess I was expecting that the kernel would be relatively low-dimensional, which would keep complexity low. But there's no reason that has to be true in general. So if that expectation does not hold, perhaps it would not help speed up the algorithm. I will edit my answer. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer since this still seems too slow to check the case `n=19, h=10` (and no "good" vectors may even exist in this case).

Here is an implementation of the checking algorithm that @vib describes, and using random sampling over all `2^(n+h-1)` vectors, in Mathematica.

```
TestFullNullSpace[A_, ns_] := Module[{dim, n},
  {dim, n} = Dimensions[ns];
  For[i = 1, i < 3^dim, i++,
   testvec = Mod[IntegerDigits[i, 3, dim].ns, 3] /. {2 -> -1};
   If[Norm[A.testvec] == 0,
    Return[False]];
   ];
  Return[True];
]

n = 17;
h = 10;

Do[
 v = Table[RandomChoice[{0, 1}], {n + h - 1}];
 A = Table[v[[i ;; i + n - 1]], {i, 1, h}];
 ns = NullSpace[A, Modulus -> 3] /. {2 -> -1};
 If[TestFullNullSpace[A, ns],
  Print[v]];,
 {1000}]
```

Sample output for the above run, after a few seconds of computation:

```
{0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0}
{1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0}
{1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0}
{0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1}
```

So from 1000 checked vectors, 4 were "good" (unless I have a bug). Unfortunately, for `n=18`, I ran this for several minutes and still didn't find a "good" vector. I don't know if they don't exist or are just exceedingly rare.

Comment: There is a way to further reduce the complexity of the algorithm I described   and you implemented but I am not going to describe it until someone tells me he cares. Anyway, bottom line is I think we can throw the 3^(n-h) complexity due to TestFullNullSpace away. This would leave us with 2^(n+h-1) * (n+h)^3 or something as a total complexity for the algorithm. Not sure whether we can live with that or not...

Comment: @vib I care! I would love to see your faster method. Did you have any luck with n = 19 and h = 10  ?

Answer (score 1):

Below is an algorithm that reduces the complexity from 3^n to 3^{n-h}.

Let v_1, v_2, .., v_h be the vectors you need to be orthogonal to.

Consider the vectorial space (Z/3Z)^n. Let v'_1, .., v'_h be the natural inclusions of v_1, .., v_h in this space.

Now let w be a vector with coefficients in {-1,0,1}, and let w' be the vector of (Z/3Z)^n obtained by naturally seeing w as a vector of (Z/3Z)^n. Then a necessary condition for w to have a zero scalar product with v_1, .., v_h (in R) is that w' has zero scalar product (in (Z/3Z)^n ) with v'_1, .., v'_h.

Now you can quite easily determine the w' that have zero scalar product with v'_1, .., v'_h. They will form a space of size 3^{n-h}. Then you need to check, for each of them, whether the associated w was actually orthogonal to all the v_i.

Comment: This would reduce the number of iterations to 5,283,615,080,448 I think.

Comment: How did you get this figure ? 3^(19-10) is only 19683. Then you have some polynomial factors but I don't think this will be as bad as you say.

Comment: The algorithm has to try all possible (0,1) arrays of length n+h-1 and for each one run your routine which takes 3^(n-h) iterations potentially doesn't it?

Comment: Right, I had not understood you wanted to test all arrays of length n-h+1.

Comment: I only test all arrays currently as I don't know a better way to find a "Good" one.

Comment: I ran some tests using an algorithm similar to what you describe, however I used random sampling over the set of all `2^(n+h-1)` candidate vectors instead of enumerating them. For the case `n=16, h=10`, "good" vectors are still very common and can be found within a fraction of a second. For `n=17, h=10`, I found a "good" vector within a few seconds. For `n=18, h=10`, I ran the program for several minutes and still didn't find one. The "good" vectors obviously become much rarer as `n` increases, and probably there is some limit above which they don't exist at all.

Comment: @cfh Thanks for the update ! That's interesting. It would be nice to know from the OP whether there are some reasons to believe that n=19 may mark this transition for h=10 ...  Another thing would be from smaller n to guess information about the structure of vectors that are good and to use this to bias the sampling in order to favour good vectors  (for instance, good vectors may contain fewer zeros)

Comment: I now posted the program as an answer, although it doesn't fully answer the question, in case somebody wants to play around with it.

Comment: `in case somebody wants to play around with it`, said body might find this easier to take literally if it was a wiki-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that reduces it to `O(n*h*3^(n/2 + 1))`.  That scales badly, but is good enough for your use case.

Iterate through every possibility for the first half of the vector.  Create a dictionary of dictionaries of ... of dictionaries of arrays whose keys are the value of each shifted inner product, and whose final value is the array of first halves of the vector that resulted in that sequence.

Now iterate through every possibility for the second half of the vector.  As you calculate each of its inner products, traverse into the nested dictionary and see if there are corresponding first halves whose contribution to the inner product still cancels.  If you traverse all of the way to the end, then you can put together the first half you found with the second half you also found and you have an answer.

Don't forget to ignore the answer that is all 0s!

Comment: This would certainly be really great if it works.  However, could you give some more detail, pseudo-code or even code please.  I don't understand exactly what you have in mind.