# How can I compute the null space/kernel (x: M·x = 0) of a sparse matrix in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I found some examples online showing how to find the null space of a regular matrix in Python, but I couldn't find any examples for a sparse matrix (`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`).

By null space I mean *x* such that *M·x* = ***0***, where '*·*' is matrix multiplication. Does anybody know how to do this?

Furthermore, in my case I know that the null space will consist of a single vector. Can this information be used to improve the efficiency of the method?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Trivially, `M * x == 0` would be true for a vector of all zeros, but I assume that's not what you want.

Comment: I suppose you must be referring to the [row null space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)#The_row_space_of_a_matrix) of the matrix, i.e. when you say *"regular row/column multiplication"* you are referring to to matrix-vector rather than elementwise multiplication.

Comment: `scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve` kind of does this, but I'm guessing it's not as efficient as finding the null space directly. From personal experience (b is non-zero) it is quite slow.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response! Yes, i am referring the the matrix-vector multiplication, and i am looking for a non-zero element x such that M * x = 0. This is possible in matrices with determinant = 0, or if the shape of the matrix is not square. Thank you simonzack, actually that is exactly what i am currently doing, but i was wondering if there was a more efficient way of finding the null space, since spsolve produces a much more general answear.

Comment: Could you give us a small example with a dense array? That would give as reference point when thinking about a sparse equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a complete answer yet, but hopefully it will be a starting point towards one. You should be able to compute the null space using a variant on the SVD-based approach shown for dense matrices [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5889142/1461210):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg


def rand_rank_k(n, k, **kwargs):
    "generate a random (n, n) sparse matrix of rank <= k"
    a = sparse.rand(n, k, **kwargs)
    b = sparse.rand(k, n, **kwargs)
    return a.dot(b)

# I couldn't think of a simple way to generate a random sparse matrix with known
# rank, so I'm currently using a dense matrix for proof of concept
n = 100
M = rand_rank_k(n, n - 1, density=1)

# # this seems like it ought to work, but it doesn't
# u, s, vh = sparse.linalg.svds(M, k=1, which='SM')

# this works OK, but obviously converting your matrix to dense and computing all
# of the singular values/vectors is probably not feasible for large sparse matrices
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(M.todense(), full_matrices=False)

tol = np.finfo(M.dtype).eps * M.nnz
null_space = vh.compress(s <= tol, axis=0).conj().T

print(null_space.shape)
# (100, 1)
print(np.allclose(M.dot(null_space), 0))
# True
```

If you know that *x* is a single row vector then in principle you would only need to compute the smallest singular value/vector of *M*. It ought to be possible to do this using [`scipy.sparse.linalg.svds`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.svds.html), i.e.:

```
u, s, vh = sparse.linalg.svds(M, k=1, which='SM')
null_space = vh.conj().ravel()
```

Unfortunately, scipy's `svds` [seems to be badly behaved](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3452) when finding small singular values of singular or near-singular matrices and usually either returns NaNs or throws an `ArpackNoConvergence` error.

I'm not currently aware of an alternative implementation of truncated SVD with Python bindings that will work on sparse matrices and can selectively find the smallest singular values - perhaps someone else knows of one?

#### Edit

As a side note, the second approach seems to work reasonably well using MATLAB or Octave's [`svds`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svds.html) function:

```
>> M = rand(100, 99) * rand(99, 100);
% svds converges much more reliably if you set sigma to something small but nonzero
>> [U, S, V] = svds(M, 1, 1E-9);
>> max(abs(M * V))
ans =    1.5293e-10
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to find a solution to the same problem. Using Scipy's svds function provides unreliable results for small singular values. Therefore i have been using QR decomposition instead. The sparseqr https://github.com/yig/PySPQR provides a wrapper for Matlabs SuiteSparseQR method, and works reasonably well. Using this the null space can be calculated as:

```
    from sparseqr import qr
    Q, _, _,r = qr( M.transpose() )
    N = Q.tocsr()[:,r:]
```