# How to find the Null Space of a matrix in Python using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

As the title says, how can I find the null space of a matrix 
i.e. the *nontrivial* solution to the equation ax=0.

I've tried to use `np.linalg.solve(a,b)`, which solves the equation ax=b. So setting `b` equal to an array of zeros with the same dimensions as matrix `a`, I only get the *trivial* solution i.e. x=0.

Comment: Did you see the question ["Python (NumPy, SciPy), finding the null space of a matrix"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889142/python-numpy-scipy-finding-the-null-space-of-a-matrix)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [SciPy Cookbook](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/RankNullspace.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import svd

def nullspace(A, atol=1e-13, rtol=0):
    A = np.atleast_2d(A)
    u, s, vh = svd(A)
    tol = max(atol, rtol * s[0])
    nnz = (s >= tol).sum()
    ns = vh[nnz:].conj().T
    return ns
```

Computes an approximate basis for the nullspace of `A`.

The algorithm used by this function is based on the singular value decomposition of `A`.

**Parameters**:

`A` : ndarray

`A` should be at most 2-D.  A 1-D array with length k will be treated as a 2-D with shape (1, k)

`atol` : float

The absolute tolerance for a zero singular value.  Singular values smaller than `atol` are considered to be zero.

`rtol` : float

The relative tolerance.  Singular values less than rtol*smax are considered to be zero, where smax is the largest singular value.

If both `atol` and `rtol` are positive, the combined tolerance is the maximum of the two; that is:

```
tol = max(atol, rtol * smax)
```

Singular values smaller than `tol` are considered to be zero.

**Return value**:

`ns` : ndarray

If `A` is an array with shape (m, k), then `ns` will be an array with shape (k, n), where n is the estimated dimension of the nullspace of `A`.  The columns of `ns` are a basis for the nullspace; each element in numpy.dot(A, ns) will be approximately zero.

Comment: This was what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

you can diagonalize your matrix:

```
eigen_vects, eigen_vals = np.linalg.eig(a)
```

you then just have to pick the eigen vectors that correspond to 0 eigenvalues (possibly accounting for numerical precision).

Example:

```
np.linalg.eig(np.ones((3,3)))

(array([ -2.22044605e-16,   3.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00]),
 array([[-0.81649658,  0.57735027,  0.        ],
        [ 0.40824829,  0.57735027, -0.70710678],
        [ 0.40824829,  0.57735027,  0.70710678]]))
```

Here the 1st and 3rd vectors are your non trivial solutions.